# Pointing subdomains to github pages

Tags: github, subdomain, redirect, github-pages

I have a situation.

Currently I have two different websites hosted at the following domains. The sites are currently hosted on Azure (although that shouldn't be relevant to this question).

```
blog.craftworkgames.com
astrid.craftworkgames.com
```

I would like to move them to github pages hosting instead. I've been working on the new pages at the following URLs.

```
craftworkgames.github.io
craftworkgames.github.io/Astrid.Framework
```

The first one hosts the blog and the second one hosts Astrid respectively.

Ultimately I would like to keep my existing URLs and point them to the new domains but from what I understand, it's going to be difficult to point the astrid.craftworkgames.com domain to the Astrid.Framework subfolder on github pages.

The other thing that bothers me about my situation is that the URL is case sensitive. For example, craftworkgames.github.io/astrid.framework gives a 404 error. I feel like this is going to be problematic when handing out the URL.

So, my question is, what options to I have?

Can I somehow point `astrid.craftworkgames.com` to `craftworkgames.github.io/Astrid.Framework` transparently.

Or, alternately, can I use an alias like `www.craftworkgames.com/astrid` that's easier to remember and type.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried a rewrite rule in httacces

Comment: I found this, it says github pages doesn't support htaccess but maybe i can do something with it, https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/

Comment: But on the azure server you should have an htaccess that can show the craftworksgames.com url while displaying content from the github url. At least that's how I understand the question

Comment: @MichaelStClair The idea is to stop using Azure completely for these sites. So even if that worked I don't want anything on the azure server at all. I probably shouldn't have even mentioned Azure in the question since it's not relevant to the solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aliasing domain names is done by replacing the A records for {blog,astrid}.craftworkgames.com with CNAME records that point to `username.github.io`. Then, so that Github knows how to redirect from each of your custom domains, you add a special "CNAME" file to your repos, where the contents are exactly the domain name you want to redirect from (in your case, "astrid.craftworkgames.com").

## Example

I setup `githubp.gjp.cc` with a CNAME record to `gpittarelli.github.io`. I then created the repo [gpittarelli.github.io](https://github.com/gpittarelli/gpittarelli.github.io) with an index.html and a CNAME file that includes exactly `githubp.gjp.cc`.

You can see it in action at: http://githubp.gjp.cc/ This behaves exactly how you want `blog.craftworkgames.com` to behave. Note that if you try to go to `gpittarelli.github.io`, github redirects to my custom subdomain.

The setup is almost exactly the same for a project page, except the index.html and CNAME files are made on a gh-pages branch. You can see an example at: http://githubp-reddit.gjp.cc/

Which is based off the `gh-pages` branch of this repo:

https://github.com/gpittarelli/reddit-twitch-bot/tree/gh-pages

## Sources

- https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/
- https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-cname-file-to-your-repository/
- https://help.github.com/articles/about-custom-domains-for-github-pages-sites/#apex-domains

Comment: Still waiting for DNS propagation but this solution appears to work perfectly! Thanks so much. In hindsight it seems almost obvious to try this, but I was confused by githubs documentation I think. I'll award the bounty in 30 mins when stackoverflow let's me.